# Nationalities extension with dual citizenship

Tags: extension

I installed the Nationalities extension and it works fine. However, there are some contacts that have dual citizenship. I was wondering if somebody has already implemented this or have ideas how to do it?

thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure we are helping you correctly can you please mention the full name of the extension? (so something like org.civicoop.nationalities)? Also, mention the version of CiviCRM you are using and what CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Is "Nationality" a group of custom fields? If so, consider making the group multi-valued.